# Objective C Update RESTful Webservice

Tags: objective-c, web-services, rest

I have a web service that allows me to update records on in our database.
The columns in the table are as follows:

- allowsActions
- assetID
- inventoryObjectID
- objectDescription
- quantity
- retired
- serialNumber
- action

I'm using the following to GET data from the webservice.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", inventoryAndActionsWebservice];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Then shoving into a dictionary like so:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"WE HAS THE DATAS");
         NSDictionary *inventory = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
        // Then storing the values in CoreData here
     }
 }
```

What would be the syntax for updating the webservice? It expects an object in the body of the service call (POST).

Comment: The app side syntax is dictated by the server side implementation. It is not possible for us to tell you how to do that without more information on the server side implementation. i.e. Does the server expect parameters in the URL (GET) or in the body of the service call (POST)

Comment: Sorry for leaving that out. It expects an object in the body of the service call. (POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the syntax that I was looking for was ultimately this:

```
NSString *jSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"MediaInventoryObjectsId\":%d,\"AssetId\":%d,\"Quantity\":%d,\"SerialNumber\":\"%@\",\"Description\":\"%@\",\"AllowActions\":%d,\"Retired\":%d}",inventoryObjectId, assetID, quantity, serialNumber, description, allowActions, retired];

// Convert jSON string to data
NSData *putData = [jSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

// Instantiate a url request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

// Set the request url format
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d", inventoryAndActionsWebservice, inventoryObjectId]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[request setHTTPBody:putData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];


// Send data to the webservice
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableURLRequest` let's you `setHTTPBody:` and setHTTPMethod:`.`@"POST"`is the way to do a post.  Most services need to know the body length and encoding set in headers.  (see`addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`) for that.

The only reason this topic is tricky is because the developer is forced to grapple with two problems at once:  what constitutes a valid request for my server, and (2) how do I form that request with iOS?  Part (2) is actually pretty easy once you get a valid request.

The best way to proceed is to get an example working using curl (or something equivalent).  Then move on to producing that request in iOS.  If you have trouble, ask a question here of the form:  "I know my server needs X, here's my code to produce X, but I'm getting this error Y".

Comment: This is very helpful. One more question. What do I set setHTTPBody to?

Comment: Sure. That's the most server-dependent part. If you're lucky, you can send json and use nsjsonserialization to serialize a dictionary. The other common requirement is name-value pairs, like a query string in the body.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but:
[request setHTTPBody: ] is looking for NSData not an NSDictionary, correct?

Comment: You're right, NSData.  That's what NSJSONSerialization returns from dataWithJSONObject...  That method takes a foundation object and returns NSData.  If you render that NSData as an NSString, you'll see it's just a JSON encoding of the object.

Comment: To clarify... yes, set http body to NSData.  That's either data from JSON serialization (my previous comment) or NSData initialized with an NSString representing a name-value query string.